# Issue with obtaining the offline messages using openfire server

Tags: openfire, smack

Offline messages are not delivering to the user when the person avails.

*DelayInformation   info = (DelayInformation)message.getExtension("x","jabber:x:delay");*

returns null.

when i iterate the collection of message.getExtensions() , i get  delay urn:xmpp:delay.

can anyone explain on this.
I'm using smack and smackx.jar. Though the smackx.jar has smack.providers it's not taken into account.

some suggested to use urn:xmpp:delay ,which results in class cast exception.

DelayInformation   inf = (DelayInformation)message.getExtension("delay","urn:xmpp:delay");

Exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.DefaultPacketExtension

Comment: give me your version of smack and runtime environment ( pure java or android )

Comment: @LinYuCheng  RunTime environment is java and using smack.jar.For your reference https://ufile.io/4vwz2

Answer (score 0):

if this is for android by using the Smack Library try this:

```
ExtensionElement delay = message.getExtension("urn:xmpp:delay");
if(message.getExtension("urn:xmpp:delay") != null){

    Log.i("RECVEIVED", "delay 1: " + delay.toXML());
    Log.i("RECVEIVED", "delay 2: " + delay.getNamespace());
    Log.i("RECVEIVED", "delay 3: " + delay.getElementName());
}
```

Log output:

```
I/RECVEIVED: delay 1: <delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' stamp='2017-07-31T04:09:23.224+00:00' from='81.89.100.197'></delay> 
I/RECVEIVED: delay 2: urn:xmpp:delay 
I/RECVEIVED: delay 3: delay
```

this is another possibillity:

```
DelayInformation delayInformation = DelayInformation.from(message);
if (delayInformation != null) {

    Log.i("RECVEIVED", "delay 1 : " + delayInformation.getStamp());
    Log.i("RECVEIVED", "delay 2 : " + delayInformation.getStamp().getTime());
}
```

Log output:

```
I/RECVEIVED: delay 1: Mon Jul 31 06:08:58 GMT+02:00 2017
I/RECVEIVED: delay 2: 1501474138319
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

According to the document:
https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/Smack-4.2-Readme-and-Upgrade-Guide

f you are developing with smack 4.2 on java 7, you need the following dependencies to make it work:

```
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-java7:4.2.0"
// Optional for XMPPTCPConnection
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.2.0"
// Optional for XMPP-IM (RFC 6121) support (Roster, Threaded Chats, …)
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.2.0"
// Optional for XMPP extensions support
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.2.0"
```

Comment: If you do not use gradle or maven, you can download jar file here:
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/igniterealtime/smack/